# Литература и история

Tags: литература

***"История — это прошлое, которое воскрешается ради настоящего" В. Гюго

История есть возможность осмыслить настоящее с критической дистанции.*** История как наука возникла в эпоху Просвещения. Пишется она людьми, значит субъективна. О каких уроках истории может идти тогда речь? А в литературном произведении происходит преломление исторических фактов через призму мировоззрения автора. Пожалуйста, пару мыслей подбросьте на эту тему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Гюго хотел сказать, что из истории (не предмета история, а из фактов истории) мы должны извлекать уроки, чтобы не повторить их в будущем. Об этом много и литературных произведений. В начале 1980-х годов А.Приставкин написал повесть «Ночевала тучка золотая» (1987). Создавалась она для себя, так как самый прозорливый сочинитель тех лет не поверил бы, что такая работа сможет увидеть свет. В своем произведении автор попытался откровенно сказать о том, что пережил сам и что больно обожгло его нервы, – мир не достоин существования, если он убивает детей.

Приставкин  первым показал, как происходила насильственная депортация целого народа, – будучи свидетелем тех трагических событий, он сумел создать мудрое и доброе произведение. Анатолий Игнатьевич рассказал о том, что чувствовал сам, когда его послали на Кавказ, известный мальчишке лишь по рисунку на коробке папирос «Казбек» – горец на коне, в бурке и снежные вершины за его мощными плечами. Война против целого народа, увиденная глазами ребенка, который не понимает ни смысла, ни цели происходящего. Главное достоинство повести в том, что именно детское сознание и поступки детдомовского ребенка, над которым издевалась целая когорта всякого рода «воспитателей», оказываются чище, благороднее, мудрее сознания и поступков тысяч взрослых людей, ослепленных яростью и безжалостно уничтожающих друг друга. Золотая тучка – это душа ребенка, чистота и незащищенность. Это феерическое видение, согревающее сердце и заставляющее его биться в тревоге – не разобьется ли эта тучка о горные вершины?

Но мы этот урок не усвоили, оттого вновь и вновь вспыхивают межнациональные конфликты, одна нация пытается уничтожить другую, а страдают снова дети, а значит - будущее.

Answer (score 2):

Даже человеческое восприятие субъективно. Объективны только математические уравнения. Всё остальное в любом случае проходить через чью-либо призму. Даже рассуждая о том, вращается ли Земля вокруг Солнца, нельзя сказать однозначно, так как ответ будет зависеть от точки, принятой за ось координат. Абсолютно не понятно, в чём можно упрекнуть историю как науку. Она, как и всё в мире, относительна. Что для одного хорошо, для другого будет плохо. Так всё устроенно.

Comment: Я историю не упрекаю, ни в коем случае. Просто пытаюсь разобраться в теме, которую получила для написания работы. Просто не совсем понятно, если история субъективна, а литература тем более, почему Гюго говорит о воскрешении её (истории) ради настоящего?

Comment: А что мешает взять чей-то опыт и применить его в настоящем? Не вижу противоречия. Мы можем разделять/не разделять позиции Сталина или Гитлера - в этом будет субъективность. Однако, ничто не мешает в будущем использовать опыт как первого, так и второго политического деятеля.

Answer (score 2):

История
 непросто субъективна, она субъективна в кубе. Читая об исторических 
событиях вы продираетесь сквозь дебри как минимум трех личностей. Первая
 - это вы сами, вторая - историк, написавший труд, а третья - автор 
источника, по которому написана работа. Чаще всего есть еще и четвертый 
пласт - непосредственный свидетель события. Все это не дает никакой 
возможности получить сколь-нибудь объективное знание об истории, а 
следовательно и возможности применить это знание для объективной оценки 
настоящего. Любая историческая аналогия крайне условна, так как различий
 всегда больше, чем сходств. Правда при этом предсказания историков и 
политологов (политология выделилась из истории в конце XIX в.) сбываются
 чаще, чем у никогда не увлекавшегося древностью человека, почему это 
происходит - по большому счету, неизвестно.

Если говорить о фразе Гюго, то к ней надо подходить с позиции принципа 
историзма и понимать, что в его времена считали возможным получения 
объективного исторического знания, критика источника была  в зачаточном состоянии, поэтому все эти вышеизложенные рассуждения Гюго не учитывал.

Answer (score 1):

Есть целое направление - философия истории. Она как раз рассматривает вопрос "Как возможна история как наука?". Никто научность истории не отрицает, вопрос лишь в том, как понимать сущность гуманитарных наук в принципе.

Но Гюго говорит не о научной точности истории, а о памяти человечества, повторяемости событий, связи времен, которая позволяет выносить уроки из прошлого. Весь ваш прошлый опыт - это история ваших достижений и ошибок, благодаря которой вы приобретаете способность давать советы, учить детей и развиваться. У человека, знающего историю человечества, кругозор шире, а его выводы более масштабны и общезначимы.

Answer (score 0):

История. Этимология: ист (сокращенная истина), ория (провозглашение; пример: оратор - провозглашающий что-то). Итак: история - провозглашение истин. По Платону истина - это представление о к.л. явлениях (объектах) людей, находящихся в различных условиях восприятия. С возникновением письменности появились описания этих явлений, которые у потомков стали вызывать (это естественно) споры. С развитием человеческих (в т.ч. международных) отношений термин история стал преимущественно относиться к сфере этих самых отношений. История не наука. Наука оперирует или открывает законы по которым можно (образно говоря) вычислить что было и что будет. Наша история не такова. (Законы исторического развития человечества не в счет; они относятся к другой области знаний.) Историю можно переделывать, подгонять, подстраивать под сиюминутные интересы сильных мира сего. И эта практика ведется с "доисторических" времен. Пресловутые "уроки истории" уроками вовсе не являются, но позволяют народам в нужный момент заявить о своей более значительной роли в истории.